# Google charts - graph within a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, django, google-visualization

I currently have a scatter chart that has the html tooltips turned on. According to the [API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#tooltip_actions) you can use any javascript (and html) in the tooltips. What I would like to do is allow the user to not only hover over a data point and see more information on it, but to also see another graph within the tooltip.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var aPart = (4 - 16) / ({{ lowest_velocity }} - {{ highest_velocity }});
        var bPart = 4 - {{ lowest_velocity }} * aPart;
        var options = {width: {{ img_width }}, height: {{ img_height }}, title: 'Results for model: {{ current_model_selection }}, build: {{ current_build_selection }}', chartArea: {left: 50, top: 100}, backgroundColor: 'transparent', colors: ['#3cb521'], legend: 'none',

            hAxis: {viewWindow: {min: {{ tunnelminx }}, max: {{ tunnelmaxx }}}, agridlines: {count: 0}}, pointSize: 8, fontName: '"Arial"',
            vAxis: {viewWindow: {min: {{ tunnelminy }}, max: {{ tunnelmaxy }}}, agridlines: {count: 0}}, tooltip: { isHtml: true },
            series: [
                {% for lst in velocity_pressure_list %}
                    {% if lst.1 == 0%} {# If pressure == 0 #}
                        {color: 'red', pointSize: aPart * {{lst.0}} + bPart},
                    {% else %} {# Else is pressure so change size #}
                        {pointSize: aPart * {{lst.0}} + bPart},
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            ]
        };
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", "table"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        var data;
        function drawChart() {
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('number', 'X');
            {% for column in num_columns %}
                data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
                data.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Probe Details', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
            {% endfor %}
            data.addRows({{ vtime_cd_list_of_lists|safe }});

            var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select',
                    function () {
                        table.setSelection([
                            {row: chart.getSelection()[0].row}
                        ]);
                    });
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
            table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
        }
    </script>
```

The parts enclosed with {{ }} are simply Django variables and likewise, {% %} are Django logic statements. If anyone has any ideas about how to go about this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There are two mechanisms that come to mind, neither would result in dynamic charts. The first mechanism would be to use the [Google Chart Image](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/chart_gall) API as the `src` in `img` tags. The second mechanism would be to [generate charts as PNG](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing), and again use the `img.src` parameters. Neither would give you a dynamic chart.

Comment: This sounds like it should be entirely possible.  I think the biggest challenge you would face in implementation is that the initializing a chart is a rather complex process.  You would need to somehow set up a  DataTable (or perhaps a DataView) for each ToolTip Chart.

I would start by developing an function that encapsulates the initialization of the chart and DataTable or DataView and takes a parameter of the container id of the chart to be drawn, and any necessary parameters for initializing the data.  Then perhaps call this function onMouseOver or similar event to draw the table.

Comment: @JeremyFaller Used the PNG method. It looks very nice and works well. If you want to add an answer I can mark it as correct. Likewise, possibly providing an example of this within the API would probably help a few people - as I've proved out that is 100% possible and looks great.

Comment: @RedShift Sure, I'll see about getting an example published, but it'd be great to see any of the code you got working. (In fact, I'll get our documentation guy to incorporate what he can of yours into the code snippet.)

Comment: @JeremyFaller, I've provided a generic answer, but I have also got it working with unique charts for each tooltip aswell - yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using the graph to png technique as suggested by JeremyFaller. My answer involves some Django, but I believe most people will get the general idea for php etc.

I have only included the relevant parts for getting graphs to show up in tooltips. Likewise, there is important information in the comments of the code. Scroll across to you don't miss any.

**This first bit is just a default chart (not dynamically created from a DB).**

```
var encoded_img;
var copy_of_data_list;
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", "table"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['x', 'Cats', 'Blanket 1', 'Blanket 2'],
        ['A', 1, 1, 0.5],
        ['B', 2, 0.5, 1],
        ['C', 4, 1, 0.5],
        ['D', 8, 0.5, 1],
        ['E', 7, 1, 0.5],
        ['F', 7, 0.5, 1],
        ['G', 8, 1, 0.5],
        ['H', 4, 0.5, 1],
        ['I', 2, 1, 0.5],
        ['J', 3.5, 0.5, 1],
        ['K', 3, 1, 0.5],
        ['L', 3.5, 0.5, 1],
        ['M', 1, 1, 0.5],
        ['N', 1, 0.5, 1]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var chart_divB = document.getElementById('chart_divB'); //chart_divB is hidden
    var chartB = new google.visualization.LineChart(chart_divB)
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartB, 'ready', function () {
        encoded_img = '<p><img src="' + chartB.getImageURI() + '"></p>'; //Creates the encoded img
    });
    var options = {title: 'Something random and cutsie about cats',
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    };

    chartB.draw(data, options); //Draws it in the hidden div (required for the png trick)
    copy_of_data_list ={{ main_graph_list_of_lists|safe }} //My Django data from a db
    for (var i = 0; i < copy_of_data_list.length; i++) {
        copy_of_data_list[i][2 * i + 2] += encoded_img; //Adds the encoded png image to the correct tooltip columns (most people will just have one, but I have other things going on)
    }
}
```

**This is the second 'proper' chart which is visible and has tooltips.**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", "table"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    var data;
    function drawChart() {
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('number', 'X');
        {% for column in num_columns %} //More stuff that is not specifically related to this problem
            data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
            data.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Probe Details', role: 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});//It is essential that the tooltip column/s is html enabled
        {% endfor %}
        data.addRows(copy_of_data_list); //The modified data thanks to the last 'chart'

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

**Taking this beyond just one tooltip chart**

This technique of using the png encoded images can be used to create different charts for each of the tooltips. By creating N hidden divs, each with their own unique id - a small modification on what I have done above can be used to achieve this. Hint: loop from the getting of the element by ID to the drawing of the chart N times (number of tooltips you have). For each of these hidden divs, with their own unique ids, you can then basically just draw hidden graphs and then convert them to pngs.

Note: if people want a better example, I will make one upon request if they can't get different tooltip charts working.